# why parent child does not inherit parent's scroll bar style

Tags: css, inheritance, scrollbar

Here's html including two parent and child divs.
Parent has a css scroll bar styling using `-webkit-scrollbar`, however child does not inherit these stylings and displays "regular" scroll bar.

Why?

```css
#childDiv{
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: inherit;
}

.parentDiv{
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  overflow: auto;
}
.parentDiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
}


.parentDiv::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: red;
  /* box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px grey;  */
}

.parentDiv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv" class="parentDiv">
    <div id="childDiv">
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
      one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line one line <br>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: The styles are set on class `parentDiv`. The child item does not have that class.

Comment: @BookOfFlames you are right, but the question refer inheritance, this is a bot different than class assignment. however, I realized with your comment to assign the scroll bar class on every element I ant to have the scroll bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:-webkit-scrollbar` is a pseudo class. `#childDiv` is a child of `#parentDiv`, but not of any `.parentDiv::-webkit-scrollbar`. You wouldn't expect `#childDiv` to inherit properties from `.parentDiv::first-letter` either. But you could write it like this:

```css
.parent::first-letter {
  color: purple;
}

.sort-of-inherit::first-letter, .sort-of-inherit *::first-letter {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  bla bla bla
  <div class="child">
    bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sort-of-inherit">
  bla bla bla
  <div class="child">
    bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```